# MKNetwork saving JSON content to NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, jsonkit

I am using `MKNetwork`, to handle the Networking functionality of my application.

I am trying to read a JSON file, and save its content to a `NSDictionary`.

```
NSDictionary *valueDic = [[completedOperation responseJSON] objectForKey:@"value"];
```

The above code (`responseJSON`)works for iOS 5 and above. i need it to work for iOS 4 too. 
The author of this framework says the following;  (see the [comments section in this post](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/products/ios-framework-introducing-mknetworkkit/))

```
Subclass MKNO and override that method and call
[super responseJSON] for iOS5 and return JSONKit(or equivalent) based dictionary for other versions
```

I have no clue how to implement this, Can someone please help me. I have been stuck in this the whole day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom subclass of the MKNO an implement the responseJSON Method like:

```
- (NSDictionary *) responseJSON {
 return [ [self responseData] objectFromJSONData];
}
```

Don't forget to include "JSONKit.h"

PS: For future projects you should use: [ASIHTTPRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/)

Comment: Thank you loads for your reply, but can you please tell me what is `self responseData` ? `objectFromJSONData` has to be a JSONKit method i guess. Am i correct ?

Comment: your MKNetworkOperation Object has a Method responseData which is the data from the request. Please read the doc/manuals from https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit/blob/master/MKNetworkKit/MKNetworkOperation.h

Comment: I took your advice, now i am using ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: meccan - Can you give some reasons for why you think future projects should use ASIHTTPRequest? According to their webpage -> http://allseeing-i.com/[request_release]; they are no longer developing/supporting it. That is why I went with MKNetworkKit in a few of my new projects.

Comment: @marked atm ASIHTTPRequest is the best sdk for URL Connection other like AFNetwork and so on, should improve some usability. At my opinion i stick at ASIHTTPRequest until, i get a better solution... And the last commit on github is from "January 22, 2012"

Comment: The reason I wrote MKNetworkKit was to make it as easy to use like ASI and be powerful. MKNetworkKit's core strength is probably built in caching, ARC compatible and easy of use.

Comment: after one project with MKNetworkKit and dozens with ASIHTTPRequest i would never go back to ASIHTTPRequest... MKNetworkKit rulez